# OP Amp as audio preamp - am I doing it right?

Tags: operational-amplifier, audio, preamp

I have a design that uses an ATXMega32E5 for two audio sources. In one case, a timer output square wave (3.3v logic) goes through a low-pass filter to make beeps, and in the other case, a DAC channel outputs 8 kHz audio samples (0-3.3v). Each goes into a 20k pot, the output of which goes into an LM4871, and into an 8Ω speaker.

The audio sounds fine, but the levels are way too low - like hold the speaker next to your ear.

I tried cranking up the LM4871 gain a little, but you're not really supposed to do that, and 3 dB of gain from the reference design didn't really make much of a difference I could hear.

I'm thinking the correct thing to do is stick an op amp (inverting configuration with half-vcc virtual ground) gain stage in.

Audio isn't really my strong suit. Can someone look over the proposed design and tell me what's wrong with it? :)

The original circuit just connects the R8/R13 output directly to C23. Everything between those two points is the addition I'm thinking of.

Note that during the test, AUDEN is high - with AUDEN low, there's no audio at all (which is the whole point of that line).
[image: schematic]

P.s. The differential output on the speaker leads (with the speaker attached) is around 2v P-P. Is it perhaps just that this speaker sucks?

Comment: LM4871 datasheet shows 20k in series with C23 [fig 3-typical circuit]. Have you left that out intentionally?

Comment: No. Someone on Twitter also mentioned that. I’m going to call that an error. 

Comment: With peak to peak DAC and beeper output voltage in the volts range you will never need extra amplification, LM4871 is quite enough. Search for error somewhere else.

Comment: @carloc That's kind of what I was thinking at the time. My conclusion was that the controller didn't have sufficient output drive for the input impedance, but that just doesn't seem reasonable.

Comment: You are right, I'd rather search for some trivial error, maybe just some part or connection broken, a wrong pinout or something alike...

Comment: Is there any chance that R16 has mistakenly been installed with a 20K resistor? That would reduce your power by a factor of 100.

Comment: The op amp portion of the circuit doesn’t yet exist. It’s a proposal.

Comment: @carloc The output (with the 8Ω speaker attached) is 2v P-P (differential). It does seem like that ought to be making more noise than it is.

Comment: broken speaker? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A commenter on my hackaday project solved the mystery. I had calculated the rolloff frequency for the LM4871 feedback incorrectly. With 0.33µF it's something like 24 Hz instead of 2.4 kHz like I wanted. Replacing it with 1000pF brought the audio right up (but 2200pF is probably a better choice).

I'd already ordered new boards with the preamp circuit, but I can always leave all of the components off and use 0Ω for the preamp feedback resistor (R16) and see which way is better.

Answer (score 0):

IC4 is configured wrong for negative feeedback.  Check datasheet.

Remove C20

Insert 20k with C23 in series for unity gain

Comment: C20 ostensibly adds some low-pass filtering to the output stage. The configuration of the amp itself is correct according to the data sheet. I believe you’re right about adding 20k in series to C23, though.

Comment: Get a DMM if you want to stop guessing.  Measure all continuity, DC AC all points start from input